# Java Program for Word Extraction Not Terminating

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The words get extracted and displayed but the program doesn't terminate.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Exp2
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter sentence");
        while(obj.hasNext())
        {
            String str1=obj.next();
            System.out.println(str1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should learn how to ask questions on SO after taking a look at your profile ..

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner#next()` with `Scanner` reading from a *console* becomes a blocking I/O call. That's why the loop would never terminate unless you explicitly `break` out of it. Something like

```
while(obj.hasNext())
{
    String str1=obj.next();
    System.out.println(str1);
    if ("quit".equalsIgnoreCase(str1)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Use "quit" or "/quit" or "/q" if you like to `break` out of the loop as shown in my answer.

> You need to understand that reading from a console blocks indefinitely because you can always type something at the prompt and that's what the program then waits for.

Standard input stream i.e. `System.in` does not behave like a file stream because there is no End of File `EOF` marker to let the `Scanner` know that no more data is available.

Comment: What condition should I use to break out of it? I can't look for a character ',' as Scanner does not accept characters as tokens.

Comment: But I want the code to exit when the sentence ends, without having to use any words to explicitly terminate the program. For eg., the word extraction could take place till *full stop*, or when there are no more words in the sentence.

Comment: Use "quit" or "/quit" or "/q" if you like to invoke break as shown in my answer. You need to understand that reading from a console blocks indefinitely because you can always type something at the prompt and that's what the program then waits for.

Comment: Standard input does not behave like a File where you have an End of File marker to let the Scanner know that no more data is available.

Comment: Thanks, but I figured I can also ask the user to enter the sentence ending with a space followed by a full stop. And I can `break` the loop the moment `str1.equals"."`, right?

Comment: No, that won't work. Use a regex pattern like `(str1.matches(".*(\\.|\\?)$"))` which returns `true` if the last charcter is a full stop or a question mark.

Comment: What happens? Are you getting an error? It works. I just tested it.

Comment: @raiGuy What about first learn a few things about Java before you try to create an iterative process like `(1) try (2) ask on SO (3) goto (1)` ..

Answer (score 0):

Scanner.next [blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) on IO to get data from standard input and hence it doesn't terminate. You need to do something like below to come out of loop:

```
 String str1 = obj.next();
 if (str1.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
    break;//break from while loop when user types exit
```

This means when you will enter exit (see that you could even give Exit as it would do a case insensitive match of exit), it will terminate your program gracefully by coming out of the loop.

Comment: so what else you could type to come out of loop any special char/string etc.?

Comment: full stop would be a good option. But that's the problem. `Scanner` class doesn't allow me to detect a character and then break the loop.